# Including a fallback solid color in a Compass Sass gradient?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am using compass on my site, and have created a style such as:

```
@include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #C9C9C9, #FFF));
```

The problem is, this doesn't incluse a solid-color fallback for older IEs.  Do I simply have to include a line like

```
background-color: #c9c9c9;
```

Or is there a way to have Compass handle this automatically for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way in Compass to have the background color automatically computed from a background-image declaration, because of the way it is built : you could have several gradients in there, and Compass can't really know which of all those colors is supposed to be the base one.

One way I advice is to create a gradient-wrapper like the following :

```css
=gradient-horizontal($startColor: #555555, $endColor: #333333)
    background-color: $endColor
    background-color: mix($startColor, $endColor) // Second possibility
    +filter-gradient($startColor, $endColor, horizontal)
    +background-image(linear-gradient(left, $startColor, $endColor))
```

Comment: thanks, where would I add this mixin? I also never saw the = used like that, what's the significance?

Comment: Also, if anyone on a Mac is interested, I found this app which I now use called [Gradient](http://www.gradientapp.com/). It can prepare its output for Compass and include the fallback line.

Comment: = is @mixin in SASS (not SCSS), sorry for the misunderstanding. And yes I recommand either Gradient just above or [Colorzilla's Gradient Editor](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).